# regex: pattern fails to match what I am looking for

Tags: python, regex

I have the following code that tries to retrieve the name of a file from a directory based on a double \ character:

```
import re

string = 'I:/Etrmtest/PZMALIo4/ETRM841_FX_Deals_Restructuring/FO_PRE\\abo_st_gas_dtd.csv'
pattern = r'(?<=*\\\\)*'
re.findall(pattern,string)
```

The reasoning behind is that the name of the file is always after a double \ , so I try to look any string which is preceeded by any text that finishes with \ .

Neverthless, when I apply this code I get the following error:

```
error: nothing to repeat at position 4
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** The concrete output I am looking for is getting the string `'abo_st_gas_dtd_csv'` as a match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is just a lookabehind, which, by itself, can't match anything.  I would use this `re.findall` approach:

```py
string = 'I:/Etrmtest/PZMALIo4/ETRM841_FX_Deals_Restructuring/FO_PRE\\abo_st_gas_dtd.csv'
filename = re.findall(r'\\([^.]+\.\w+)$', string)[0]
print(filename)  # abo_st_gas_dtd.csv
```

Comment: I think there is something missing in your proposal, the `re.findall` function has a positional argument missing, namely the string to find the pattern on

Comment: @Mauro Sorry...I copied my code wrongly from the Python console.

Answer (score 3):

There's a couple of things going on:

1. You need to declare your string definition using the same `r'string'` notation as for the pattern; right now your `string` only has a single backslash, since the first one of the two is escaped.
2. I'm not sure you're using `*` correctly. It means "repeat immediately preceding group", and not just "any string" (as, e.g., in the usual shell patterns). The first `*` in parentheses does not have anything preceding it, meaning that the regex is invalid. Hence the error you see. I think, what you want is `.*`, i.e., repeating any character 0 or more times. Furthermore, it is not needed in the parentheses. A more correct regexp would be `r'(?<=\\\\).*'`:

```py
import re

string = r'I:/Etrmtest/PZMALIo4/ETRM841_FX_Deals_Restructuring/FO_PRE\\abo_st_gas_dtd.csv'

pattern = r'(?<=\\\\).*'

re.findall(pattern,string)
```

Comment: My `string` is actually a list of strings, just picked the first one to make the example reproducible, how can I convert a list of strings to a list of raw strings?

Comment: Well, "raw" here is just way of declaring the string in your code. The only difference is that in this mode the backslash is treated as a symbol instead of using it for escaping other characters. The result in either case is just a string. E.g., `r'abc'` is the same as `'abc'` (there's no ``\``), while `r'\n'` is the same as `'\\n'` (in the second case the backslash is escaped), which is different from `'\n'` (a new line symbol). So, to answer your question, there is no need to convert, as long as they are defined properly in the first place, i.e., they use ``\\`` to speparate the file name.

Answer (score 1):

```
files = 'I:E\\trm.csvest/PZMALIo4\ETRM841_FX_.csvDeals_Restructuring/FO_PRE\\abo_st_gas_dtd.csv'
counter = -1
my_files = []
for f in files:
    counter += 1
    if ord(f) == 92:#'\'
        temp = files[counter+1:len(files)]
        temp_file = ""
        for f1 in temp:
            temp_file += f1
            # [0-len(temp_file)] => if [char after . to num index of type file]== csv
            if f1 == '.' and temp[len(temp_file):len(temp_file)+3] == "csv":
                my_files.append(temp_file + "csv")
                break
print(my_files)#['trm.csv', 'ETRM841_FX_.csv', 'abo_st_gas_dtd.csv']
```